# How to create object of object inside

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Here is my code

```
    let tmp_ff = Object.fromEntries(
        this.choosen_products.flatMap((element, index) => [     
        [`q_p${index + 1}_fullname`, element.p_fullname],
        [`q_p${index + 1}_code`, element.p_code],
        [`q_p${index + 1}_category`, element.p_category],
        [`q_p${index + 1}_cost`, element.p_cost],
        [`q_p${index + 1}_margin`, element.p_margin],
        [`q_p${index + 1}_sell`, element.p_sell],
]),
```

I want to create object inside object start from the choosen_products index 1 like here below:

```
tmp_ff{
1: {choosen_products elements...}
2: {choosen_products elements...}
3: {choosen_products elements...}
}
```

How to create the object name 1, object name 2. The one I create is flatMap and cannot decalre another object name "1", how can I switch flapMap to object and assign the 1 , 2, 3 on each `this.choosen_products`? Please helping me with that, I've struggle for a long time.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data with expected outputs?

Comment: Also, how do you determine the indexes to go up to?